# Firebase GeoCoder returns null

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am writing uber clone app.

I want to mark drivers close to me on the map.
The location information of online drivers is kept in the Firebase that's why I use geoCoder.

My codes here:

```
addressList = geoCoder.getFromLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude, 
cityName = addressList[0].locality
```

when i run it gives this error and app crashes:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: addressList[0].locality must not be null
    at
```

When I change
cityName = addressList[0].locality
to
cityName = addressList[0].subAdminArea.
App is not crashing and I reach locations of drivers but can not see the markers on the map again

My firebase structure is ;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr29V.png

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image.

Comment: I edited , thants for your interest.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **600** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Take a moment and check [How do I ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).